# I have some kind of assertion error in my little program

Tags: c++, assertion

I have a kind of assertion error in this program, and unfortunately I'm quite new to C++ and have no idea what this means:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime> // for time()
#include <windows.h> // for Sleep()

using namespace std;

string TakingInput()
{
    cout << "What do you want to say? ";
    string a;
    getline(cin, a);
    return a;
}

// Generate a random number between nLow and nHigh (inclusive)
unsigned int GetRandomNumber(int nLow, int nHigh)
{
    return (rand() % (nHigh - nLow + 1)) + nLow;
}
string jokeplease(string strInput)
{
    while (strInput.compare("jokeplease") == 0)
    {
        cout << endl;
        // This generates a randomnumber
        int nRandomNumber = GetRandomNumber(1, 10);

        // Every joke has a number which when stated true will show the specified joke
        if(nRandomNumber == 1)
        {
            cout << "Alle barna skrev dikt unntatt Ruben, for han kunne ikke rime." << endl;
        }
        else if(nRandomNumber == 2)
        {
            cout << "Gubben va på kafe og overhørte følgende fra et forelsket par: ”Olga æ e så\n" <<
                    "forelska i dæ at når æ ser på dæ så klar æ næsten ikke å ta te mæ føde.” Gubben\n" <<
                    "syns at det dær va fine ord som han skulle overføre på kjærringa når han kom\n" <<
                    "hjem. Da dæm satt i kjøkkenkroken å kosa sæ med en kopp kaffe, så utbrøut han:\n" <<
                    "”Marta, når æ ser på dæ, så mest æ reint matløsta!”" << endl;
        }
        else if(nRandomNumber == 3)
        {
            cout << "Alle barna så inn i komfyren untatt Knut han så ut." << endl;
        }
        else if(nRandomNumber == 4)
        {
            cout << "En blondine kjører bak en lastebil og gir signal til sjåføren om å stoppe,\n" << 
                    "sjåføren stopper og blondine sier \"du mister lasten din\", sjåføren bare kjører\n" <<
                    "vidre. etter litt gir blondine signal om at han skal stoppe igenn og hun sier\n" << 
                    "\"du mister lasta di!\" sjåføren bryr seg ikke og kjører vidre. etter litt gir\n" << 
                    "blondine signal om at sjåføren skal stoppe og sjåføren sier \"du, det er midt på\n" << 
                    "vinteren, og jeg er ute og strør\"" << endl;
        }
        else if(nRandomNumber == 5)
        {
            cout << "Alle barna gjorde fra seg i potta utenom Hanne, hun gjorde det i spannet." << endl;
        }
        else if(nRandomNumber == 6)
        {
            cout << "Noen plasser sjekker legen hva barnet kommer til å bli ved å stikke hånden\n" <<
                    "sin opp i ræven på ungen. Hvis det skriker blir det en sanger, hvis det sparker\n" <<
                    "vil det bli en fotballspiller og hvis det smiler blir den en homse." << endl;
        }
        else if(nRandomNumber == 7)
        {
            cout << "Norsken, dansken og svensken skulle bade i et badebaseng. Når de kom til\n" << 
                    "badebasenget sa en dame: Det basenget er magisk. Du får et ønske. Da de kom\n" <<
                    "bort til bassenget sa norsken: Jeg ønsker meg masse sjokolade. Så ble bassenget\n" << 
                    "helt fullt med masse sjokolade. Så spiste han det opp. Så sa dansken: jeg ønsker\n" << 
                    "meg masse bananer. Så var det masse bananer i bassenget. Så gikk svensken bort\n" << 
                    "til bassenget, og så sklei han på bananskallet til dansken. Så sa han skitt og\n" << 
                    "da ble bassenget helt fullt med dritt." << endl;
        }
        else if(nRandomNumber == 8)
        {
            cout << "Tre gutter ble sendt til rektor.\n" <<
                    "\"Hva har dere gjort for noe galt da?\" spurte rektor.\n" <<
                    "\"Jeg har kastet stein i vannet\", svarte den ene.\n" <<
                    "…" <<
                    "\"Tja, det er vel ikke så farlig\", sa rektor.\n" <<
                    "\"Men hva har du gjort da?\" sa han til den andre.\n" <<
                    "\"Jeg har også kastet stein i vannet.\"\n" <<
                    "\"Det er vel ikke så farlig. Hva har du gjort da?\" sa han til den tredje.\n" <<
                    "\"Det er jeg som er Stein…\"" << endl;
        }
        else if(nRandomNumber == 9)
        {
            cout << "En brunette og en blondine hopper ut fra et fly. Hvem lander først, og hvorfor?\n" <<
                    "Brunetta lander først, fordi blondina stopper 5 ganger for å spørre om veien." << endl;
        }
        else if(nRandomNumber == 10)
        {
            cout << "Martin: - Gaute er god til å kaste ball.\n" <<
                    "Mor: - Jasså?\n" <<
                    "Martin: - Ja, han traff lillebroren sin i hodet fra 5 meter!" << endl;
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "Error: Unexpected result when retrieving randomnumber!" << endl;
        }
        cout << endl;
        return 0;
    }
    return 0;
}
void OtherStatements(string strInput)
{
    if(strInput.compare("what") == 0||strInput.compare("what?") == 0||strInput.compare("WHAT?") == 0)
    {
        cout << "WHAT?? WHAAAAAAAAAAAAAAT? WHHHAEEEHT? WHAEET WHAET ...";
        Sleep(3000);
        cout << "what?" << endl;
    }
}
string ExitTime(string strInput)
{
    while (strInput.compare("bedtime") == 0||strInput.compare("leave") == 0)
    {
        cout << "Do you want to leave? ";
        string strExitLine;
        getline(cin, strExitLine);
        if (strExitLine.compare("yes") == 0||strExitLine.compare("YES") == 0)
        {
            cout << endl;
            cout << "Whatever! I'm bored!" << endl; 
            cout << "See you later!" << endl;
            exit(1);
        }   
        else if (strExitLine.compare("no") == 0||strExitLine.compare("NO") == 0)
        {
            cout << endl;
            cout << "Well stop whining then!" << endl;
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            cout << endl;
            cout << "I'm a bloddy computer! Speak computer-friendly!" << endl;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    cout << "JokePlease v0.01\n" << endl;


        // Taking an input from the user
        string strInput = TakingInput();

        // This prints a random joke when jokeplease is entered
        jokeplease(strInput);

        // Other statements than jokeplease goes here
        OtherStatements(strInput);

        // Here you come when it's time to leave!
        ExitTime(strInput); 

    return 0;
}
```

I can compile my program without getting any errors, but at once i write something into the console-cin (found inside the `TakingInput` function), it crashes, and prints an error.

The expression printed in the error message says `Expression: invalid null pointer`, and something about ... `c:\program ... include\xtring line: 930`.

Please help me little newbie.

Comment: Reduce the code. Try removing a few lines; if the problem disappears, put them back in. If the problem remains, try again, removing a few more lines. Soon you will have the bug isolated in a small piece of code.

Comment: For better readability use switch in jokeplease!

Comment: For better readability use an array of `const char` in `jokeplease` instead of `if/then/else` ladder.

Comment: 1. Did that for several hours @Beta SEVERAL WASTED HOURS! Are planning to make a switch instead of if's and else's inside Jokeplease. Thomas Matthews: I would love to do that if I knew how, but for now I prior a switch. Thanks for feedback everyone!

Comment: Hagbag, please don't be offended, I mean this as friendly criticism: it should not have taken hours. I reduced it down to ten lines in a few minutes, but was not quick enough to post before Jason (and kicked myself for not seeing the error sooner). 1) as you say 0:00-6:00 is not a good time to debug, 2) fast and ruthless cutting is a valuable skill, 3) you should never let code get this big before testing it, and never add to code that doesn't work. Welcome to C++ programming!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are returning a zero-value (i.e., an integer) in a function that should be returning a `std::string` object with both your `jokeplease` and `ExitTime` functions.  Since both functions are passing back a temporary `string` object, the compiler has to initialize the object from some value (or use a default-constructor).  In your current scenario, you are trying to initialize it with basically a pointer to `NULL` rather than a pointer to a valid string literal (i.e., `std::string` is being called with the constructor that takes a `const char*` argument, and you're passing it a NULL-pointer).

When looking at both functions, it actually doesn't appear as though they should be returning anything, i.e., you should be making both of them `void`.

Comment: THANKS BIGTIME" @Jason. I didn't think of that. As I said I'm very new at coding in C++, and I started learning C++ two weeks ago. PROBLEM SOLVED! GOD I WASTED 6 hours of debuging with no results last night, and I feel sick today. RULE: Never debug your programs from 0-6 in the morning!

Comment: PS: Definitely coming back to this site!

Answer (score 0):

You cannot write to `cin`.  It is input only.
Change to writing to `cout`.

If this is not resolving your issue, please clarify your question.

**Edit 1:**
Per the O.P.'s question, "but at once i write something into the cin inside the ", thus an error is writing to `cin`.

Comment: Sorry, where is the code writing to cin? And how would the code even compile if that was the case?

Comment: @R. Martinho Fernandes:  Per the O.P's question, "but at once i write something into the cin inside the..".  The question says there is writing to `cin`.

Comment: @Thomas I assume he means something along the lines of "as soon as I provide any (console-)input..." instead. But perhaps he can clarify because it is somewhat confusing.

Comment: Yes, I was a little bit fast with my formulation. I ment that RUNNING THE PROGRAM i can't get any further than to giving an input. The input never reaches the while statements in the functions called further down into main, which is the purpose, because the Asserts Error pops up. Really I just don't know what's wrong with my code, and would be very happy if anyone could help me find the error(s)/bug(s) inside my program.